# Format file extensions File dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, file-extension

I don't want the extensions to be displayed by standard way with the wildcard all over the place.

If I put

```
dlg.Filter = "All admitted files (*.unv; *.uff; *.f06; *.txt) |*.unv;*.uff;*f06;*.txt|Universal file (*.unv)|*.unv|All files|*.*"
```

I obviously get

> All admitted files (*.unv; *.uff; *.f06; *.txt)

If I try to remove that first part, say I only write "All admitted files", automatically I get the ending with wildcards. The only way I could make a change is to write something like this:

```
dlg.Filter = "All admitted files (*.unv; .uff; .f06; .txt) |*.unv;*.uff;*f06;*.txt
```

Note that the last 3 wildcards are missing. The result is:

```
All admitted files (*.unv; .uff; .f06; .txt)
```

If I remove the first wildcard the default style is used. Is there a way to change this?

This is obviously the last thing I should care of, but just for the sake of learning.

Comment: I doubt this will be easy (although happy to be proven wrong :D) because this is standard dialog behaviour in Windows. If you open any standard dialog it will always display wildcards.

Comment: It doesn't even make much sense to do, they can only give the file one extension and should either A) have the power to call it what they want (where `(*.*)` should do as the placeholder for "any" (note, not "all")) or B) it should use a default format. Listing all is silly.

Comment: All admitted files | *.unv; *.uff; *.f06; *.txt 
Doesn't that work??(works on win8) you simple want only the text right?

Comment: This string only is not showing me the file extensions: `"All admitted files|*.unv;*.uff;*f06;*.txt|Universal file|*.unv|All files|*.*"`